# How to create multiple arrays at one time

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.zeros(100)
b = np.zeros(100)
c = np.zeros(100)
```

is urgly.

However,

```
a,b,c = np.zeros(100)
```

doesn't work.

Comment: You could make one multi dimensional array rather than 3 arrays

Comment: Have you tried a,b,c = np.zeros((100,3))?

Comment: How are you going to use these 3 arrays?  Iterating through each to set nonzero values is not a good idea.  Assigning blocks of values is fine.  But why 3 (or more)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension:

```
a,b,c = [np.zeros(100) for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: Great solution, but minor nit: since `i` is unused here, you could instead use the throwaway `_`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that a,b,c have roughly the same life time, then

```
a,b,c = np.zeros((3,100))
```

is a good and fast solution, otherwise it's a memory leak.

Always works:

```
a,b,c = (np.zeros(100) for _ in "abc")
```

Note that `_` being a dummy iterating over a string is no less meaningful (and faster) than using `range(3)`.

Similarly, for just three terms

```
a,b,c = [np.zeros(100) for _ in "abc"]
```

is actually slightly faster than the generator expression.

Even faster:

```
a,b,c = map(np.zeros,3*(100,))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid statement since you are trying to assign a single array object to the three different objects:

```
a,b,c = np.zeros(100)
```

Other than list comprehension, you can also use the following:

```
a,b,c = np.zeros(100), np.zeros(100), np.zeros(100)
```

Edit: You can also just use `a,b,c = np.zeros((3,100))` as mentioned by [@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)

Comment: That's what I mentioned: `This is not a valid statement since you are trying to assign a single array object to the three different objects`.

Comment: Actually it tries to split the RHS into 3 parts.   `a,b,c = np.zeros((3,100))` does work, producing 3 1d views of the RHS array.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind `a`, `b` and `c` being the same array, you can also do it this way:

```
a, b, c = [np.zeros(100)] * 3
```

which is reasonably succinct. Otherwise, you can try @marc-dillar's method using a list comprehension instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (pure numpy):

```
a,b,c = np.zeros((3,100))
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, are you sure this works?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = b = c = np.zeros(100)
```

assigns the same array to 3 variables

```
a,b,c = np.zeros((3,100))
```

This unpacking performs an iteration on the RHS, effectively

```
a,b,c = list(np.zeros((3,100))
a,b,c = [row for row in np.zeros((3,100))]
```

These will all be `views` of the original RHS.  Instead of assigning to 3 variables, you could work with

```
abc = np.zeros((3,100))
```

But it's hard to choose among the alternatives without knowing how you will use them.  These are just a stepping stone toward creating more useful arrays.

```
In [285]: abc = np.zeros((3,10),int)
In [286]: abc[0,:] = 1
In [287]: abc[1,:] = np.arange(10)
In [288]: abc[2,:] = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
In [289]: abc
Out[289]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [4, 2, 9, 9, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0, 5]])
```